# Polymorphic association with joint table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I posted a message yesterday but I think I was not enough specific in my question.

I'm creating an event system and having difficulty with my polymorphic association.

the events can be either be:

- **National** : broadcasted for the whole group (a group has many shops)
- **Local** : broadcasted for one or more shops

I have 2 types of jingles that will be broadcasted at the same time after reaching a threshold:

- **specific_media** : media broadcasted in the shop that reached the threshold
- **generic_media** : media broadcasted in the other shops of the group when the specific media is broadcasted in the shop that reached the treshold.

my models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :specific_media, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :generic__media, polymorphic: true
  has_many :event_joins
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_joins, allow_destroy: true


class EventJoin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :event
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_joins, as: :eventable
  has_many :events,
           :through => :event_joins
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_joins, as: :eventable
  has_many :events, 
           :through => :event_joins
end
```

tables:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string  :title
      t.references :specific_media, polymorphic: true
      t.references :generic_media, polymorphic: true
      t.string  :created_by_id
      t.string  :updated_by_id
      t.float   :threshold
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :events
  end
end


class CreateEventJoins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :event_joins do |t|
      t.integer :event_id
      t.references :eventable, polymorphic: true
      t.boolean :is_active, default: true
      t.string  :created_by
      t.string  :updated_by
    end
   add_index :event_joins, [:eventable_id, :eventable_type]
  end

  def down
    drop_table :event_joins
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
  def index
    @search   = Search.new(params[:search])
    @shop = find_user_shop(@search.shop_id)
    @events = @shop.events
  end

   def new
     @event = Event.new
   end

   def create
     @search   = Search.new(params[:search])
     @shop = find_user_shop(@search.shop_id)
     @events = @shop.events
     @event = @events.new(params[:event])
     if @event.save!
       flash.now[:notice] = "Votre événement a bien été enregistré"
       render :index
     else
       flash.now[:error] = "Erreur lors de l'enregistrement du événement"
       render :new
    end
  end
```

The event-join table is empty.
Where am I going wrong in this polymorphic association ?

I want the event_type to be either Shop (local) or Group (national).

Best regards,

Comment: I can't understand the purpose of `EventJoin` here. Maybe you can write `belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true` straight into the `Event` model

Comment: I created a joint table in order to contain only generic information in event. I don't want the the model to be directly tied to the to a group or a shop.

Comment: I don't think you want `source => :eventable` there and it should be `through :event_joins` (plural)